# Get big box image name whenever it changes

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an image input that allows me to select multiple images.

Images can be previewed in boxes.

How can I get the name of the image that is in the big box each time I drag or change boxes between the images?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmdm5p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Component.ts**

```
 detectFiles(event) {

    var self = this;
    this.files = event.target.files;
    let formData = new FormData();

    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
      var n = event.target.files[0].name;
      var t = event.target.files[0].type;
      var s = event.target.files[0].size;

      self.filename = n;
      self.fileType = t;
      self.fileSize = s;
    }

    if (this.files.length < 8) {
      for (let index = 0; index < this.files.length; index++) {

        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e: any) => {
          this.urls.push(e.target.result);
          var image = new Image();
          image.src = e.target.result;
          image.onload = function () {
            self.sizeH = image.width;
            self.sizeV = image.height;
          };

        }
        formData.append('file', this.files[index]);
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[index]);
      }
    }
  }

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.urls, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }

  dropBig(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.urls, event.previousIndex, 0);
  }
```

Comment: You have to store all those data in your items list. Instead of just storing urls use an array that stores everything you need about the images.

Comment: @cy3er That is, should I create an array that does the same as the urls array? By the way, thanks for the reply.

Comment: yes, just replace the urls array with an array that holds all the properties name, size, type, res and url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store all the properties in you array.

Instead of these:

```
files:any;
sizeH:any;
sizeV:any;
filename:any;
fileType:any;
fileSize:any;

urls = new Array<string>();
```

You just need one array:

```
items = [];
```

In that array you store everything about the images:

```
const self = this;
const files = event.target.files;
const formData = new FormData();

this.items = [];
if (files.length < 8) {
    for (let index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {

        const item: any = {
            filename: event.target.files[index].name,
            fileType: event.target.files[index].type,
            fileSize: event.target.files[index].size,
        };
        this.items.push(item);

        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e: any) => {
            item.url = e.target.result;
            const image = new Image();
            image.src = e.target.result;
            image.onload = function () {
                item.sizeH = image.width;
                item.sizeV = image.height;
            };

        }
        formData.append('file', files[index]);
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[index]);
    }
}
```

And then you need to use that array in your html template.

In the `drop` method you can always find the name by the index.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-camzra)

Comment: I didn't want to be messing with the array of urls, because that's where I set the positions for the images and what "allows" me to drag the images. If you apply this the images do not appear :(

Comment: @HarryJames added stackblitz link

Comment: I was not using arrays, because if you choose 2 images at first and then select two more, I get 4. This way, whenever I select a new image, it only has the images of that new selection. Can you collect the image information as it is, but at the same time continue to "add" the selected images?

Comment: Just remove the `this.items = [];` line in the `detectFiles` method. See stackblitz.

Comment: It was perfect, thank you for your help! Best regards